# Find external weblinks in chat messages ionic

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, chatbot, livechat

I am working on a chat app in Ionicframework, i am sending and receiving the texts successfully via Sockets. There is one thing that is bugging me that:-

`How can i find out if a message contains some external weblink e-g https://google.com etc...`

I mean how other chat apps like Whatsapp filter out the external links in the messages.

I am not sure how to do that. I am thinking of following

Split out every word in the the message using `space` and then loop over every string to find out if starts with `https://` or `http://`.

I am not sure if its the better way of doing it.

Please guide me how to do it or is there any NPM library that i may use?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: regex(Regular_Expressions). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions, learn some basic regex first and then built as per your requirements.